# ARCore ObjectRenderer detect object is in Camera frame

Tags: arcore, glsurfaceview

I am looking to show some helper text on the GLSurfaceView. But I want to show this only when I see the object in my Camera's frame not before that. How can I detect whether the 3d object is visible in the Camera's frame or not?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having to check every time what objects are in the camera frame, it might be easier, deepening on your particular application, to simply attach the helper text below or above the object you want it to apply to, on the same anchor.

This would also have the advantage that the text would be centred only when the object is centred - i.e. you would not have the text suddenly fully appear when just a corner of the object is in the camera view.

ViewRenderables allow you to render 'a 2D Android view in 3D space by attaching it to a Node with setRenderable(Renderable)'.

(https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/rendering/ViewRenderable)